# How to fetch row from custom table in drupal 7?

Tags: mysql, drupal, drupal-7

I have used

```
 $member_id = 12;

 $results = db_query("select * from {customorders} where id = :fid", array(':fid' => $member_id));
 foreach($results as $result) {
       $name = $result['name'];
 }
```

but I get error `Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array`

so what could be solution , and please correct me if I have written wrong query for select

i want "select * from customorders where id = 12"
and customorders is my created custom table in Drupal database

Please help me..

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$result` variable is returned as an array of objects. So you should use `$result->name` instead of `$result['name']`.

Your code can be fixed to be like that:

```
 $member_id = 12;

 $results = db_query("select * from {customorders} where id = :fid", array(':fid' => $member_id));
 foreach($results as $result) {
       $name = $result->name; // THE EDITED LINE.
 }
```

Hope this works... Muhammad.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
$member_id = 12;

 $results = db_query("select * from {customorders} where id = :fid", array(':fid' => $member_id))->fetchAll();
 foreach($results as $result) {
       $name = $result->name; // THE EDITED LINE.
 }
```

Note the `fetchAll()` which resulted in the actual data, without this I got the database object only.